# How to compare two circuits based on their utilization

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, vivado

I have some hardware IPs that I need to synthesize. And the IP contains several generic parameters I can play with. Each combination of parameters gives me a different utilization report after synthesis and implementation.

So for example for two different configurations `Design_1` and `Design_2`, I get the following in Vivado 2018.1. The 3rd line is the ratio of the values of Design_2 devided by values of Design_1.

So as you can see in this simple example, Design_2 has less Slice LUTs but slightly more F7 Muxes.

My question is how to conclude about the cost of each one? Should I privilege Slice LUTs or Registers ...etc?

```
+----------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------+------+------------+--------------+-------------+------------+----------+---------+------------+---------+---------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+--------+--------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+---------+--------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------+---------+----------+-----------+---------+
|   Name   |    Slice LUTs     | Slice Registers |     F7 Muxes     | F8 Muxes |       Slice       |   LUT as Logic    | LUT as Memory | LUT Flip Flop Pairs | Block RAM Tile | DSPs | Bonded IOB | Bonded IPADs | PHY_CONTROL | PHASER_REF | OUT_FIFO | IN_FIFO | IDELAYCTRL | IBUFDS  | PHASER_OUT/PHASER_OUT_PHY | PHASER_IN/PHASER_IN_PHY | IDELAYE2/IDELAYE2_FINEDELAY | ILOGIC | OLOGIC | BUFGCTRL |  BUFIO  | MMCME2_ADV | PLLE2_ADV | BUFMRCE | BUFHCE |  BUFR   | BSCANE2 | CAPTUREE2 | DNA_PORT | EFUSE_USR | FRAME_ECCE2 | ICAPE2  | PCIE_2_1 | STARTUPE2 |  XADC   |
+----------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------+------+------------+--------------+-------------+------------+----------+---------+------------+---------+---------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+--------+--------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+---------+--------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------+---------+----------+-----------+---------+
| Design_1 |             34124 |           16913 |             1453 |       91 |             10272 |             31538 |          2586 |                9020 |             37 |   11 |        125 | 0            |           1 |          1 |        4 |       2 |          1 | 0       |                         4 |                       2 |                          16 |     16 |     46 |       10 | 0       |          2 |         2 | 0       |      2 | 0       |       4 | 0         | 0        | 0         | 0           | 0       | 0        | 0         | 0       |
| Design_2 |             34097 |           16913 |             1550 |       91 |             10189 |             31511 |          2586 |                9021 |             37 |   11 |        125 | 0            |           1 |          1 |        4 |       2 |          1 | 0       |                         4 |                       2 |                          16 |     16 |     46 |       10 | 0       |          2 |         2 | 0       |      2 | 0       |       4 | 0         | 0        | 0         | 0           | 0       | 0        | 0         | 0       |
| -------- |                   |                 |                  |          |                   |                   |               |                     |                |      |            |              |             |            |          |         |            |         |                           |                         |                             |        |        |          |         |            |           |         |        |         |         |           |          |           |             |         |          |           |         |
| (2)/(1)  | 0.999208768022506 |               1 | 1.06675843083276 |        1 | 0.991919781931464 | 0.999143889910584 |             1 |    1.00011086474501 |              1 |    1 |          1 | #DIV/0!      |           1 |          1 |        1 |       1 |          1 | #DIV/0! |                         1 |                       1 |                           1 |      1 |      1 |        1 | #DIV/0! |          1 |         1 | #DIV/0! |      1 | #DIV/0! |       1 | #DIV/0!   | #DIV/0!  | #DIV/0!   | #DIV/0!     | #DIV/0! | #DIV/0!  | #DIV/0!   | #DIV/0! |
+----------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------+------+------------+--------------+-------------+------------+----------+---------+------------+---------+---------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+--------+--------+----------+---------+------------+-----------+---------+--------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------+---------+----------+-----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's depending on your needs, **LUTs** and **F7 Muxes** are differents physical cells in your FPGA. So even if you don't use its, its will be there.

If you have one ressource more critical than the other, you should try to minimize the utilisation of the critical ressource to simplify the place and route.

If you have nothing critical, I think the better is to use **F7 Muxes** first because **Slice LUTs** are more flexible for the rest of your design.